# If $M$ is an $R$-module and $A,B,C$ are submodules of $M$ and $B$ is a submodule of $C$ then $A+ (B\cap C)=(A + B)\cap C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

How to show that $A+ (B\cap C)=(A + B)\cap C$ if  $M$ is an $R$-module and $A,B,C$ are submodules of $M$ and $B$ is a submodule of $C$?

Comment: Have you made any attempts yet? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one hint: you have the problem statement incorrect. Think of what happens if $A=M$ and $B=C=\{0\}$.

The correct formulation given your same assumptions should be $B+(A\cap C)=(A+B)\cap C$.

To show this you will want to show that they are equal as sets. One inclusion is straightforward. To see $(A+B)\cap C\subset B+(A\cap C)$, take $c=a+b\in (A+B)\cap C$ for $a\in A, b\in B, c\in C$. Note $B\subset C$ so $b\in C$; thus $a=c-b\in C$. So $a\in A\cap C$. What can we conclude?